# iOS - Showing currency without cents using NSNumberFormatter

Tags: ios, nsnumberformatter

I'm able to convert a particular NSNumber into currency using NSNUmberFormatter. Its showign $ symbol, numbers separated by "," etc.
But I don't want to display cents. 
For example its displaying $537,335.32
I just want to display $536,335
I'm writing the following code:

```
NSNumberFormatter *currencyFormatter = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[currencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];

NSDictionary* tempDict = [self.displayDict objectForKey:kConservative];
conservativeHP.text = [currencyFormatter stringFromNumber:[tempDict objectForKey:kHomePrice]];
```

How should I create NSNumberFormatter or do something so that the result won't have "decimals"

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Before adding the number to the formatter, change it to int to avoid the decimals, something like this:

```
float myValue = 543.32;

NSNumber myNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt: (int)myValue)];
```

You will get rid of the decimal part!

Comment: Thanks, this is good solution if I'm creating the NSNumber. But the problem is that I'll get the data from server which I cannot change. Only during display, I want to truncate cents.

Comment: You dont need to change your original value, just copy the number in a int variable, I dont see the problem

Comment: If you want to do it correctly, use [numberFormatter setRoundingMode:NSNumberFormatterRoundDown];

Answer (score 54):

Use the maximumFractionDigits setting:

```
NSNumberFormatter *currencyFormatter = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[currencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[currencyFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
```

You can adjust the value accordingly. Using 2 will limit the result to two digits, for this question a value of 0 should do it.

Comment: As an aside to this answer, adding [currencyFormatter setMinimumFractionDigits:0]; will get you numbers that round off the decimals when equal to zero. In my case, I want to show $126k, or $1.25M. This allows me to get that.

Answer (score 16):

Here is solution in **swift 3**

```
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = .currency
    //formatter.locale = NSLocale.current
    formatter.currencySymbol = "" //In case you do not want any currency symbols
    formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0
```

Setting the `maximumFractionDigits` to `0` will not show any decimal or fractional values.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3:

```
currencyFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

When you go to display it just do this

```
Mylabel.text = @"%.2f", mynumberwithcents;
```

This only works if the `mynumberwithcents` variable is either a Float or a Double...

Answer (score 0):

```
In case of using category:

    .h
        #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

        @interface NSString (Price)

        + (NSString *)updateStringToPriceWithValue:(NSNumber *)value;

        @end
    .m
        #import "NSString+Price.h"
        @implementation NSString (Price)

        + (NSString *)updateStringToPriceWithValue:(NSNumber *)value
        {
            NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
            [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];

            NSInteger minimumFractionDigits = [formatter minimumFractionDigits];
            NSInteger maximumFractionDigits = [formatter maximumFractionDigits];

            NSString *formatted = [formatter stringFromNumber:value];
            NSLog(@"%@", formatted);

            [formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:minimumFractionDigits];
            [formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:maximumFractionDigits];



            return formatted;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
extension NumberFormatter {

static func makeDisplayPrice(byCode code: String, price: Int) -> String {
    let currencyFormatter = NumberFormatter.currencyPrice
    currencyFormatter.currencyCode = code
    guard let priceString = currencyFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(integerLiteral: price)) else { return "" }
    return priceString
}

static var currencyPrice: NumberFormatter {
    let currencyFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    currencyFormatter.usesGroupingSeparator = false
    currencyFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
    currencyFormatter.locale = Locale.current
    currencyFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0
    return currencyFormatter
}
```

}

```
let displayPrice = NumberFormatter.makeDisplayPrice(byCode: currency, price: price)
```